# Multiplicity and aggregation in abstract class

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Can I do aggregation between an abstract class and a concret class?.

Example:

```
Concrete class: Enterprise
- int cod;
- String name;
- List<Office> listoffice;
//methods

Abstract class: Office
- int cod;
- String name;
- List<Enterprise> listenterprise;
//Methods
```

Remembering, Office class will have a concrete class to instance object with inheritance later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I suppose that `Enterprise` is the owner of the aggregation relation and `Office` is the target of the relation.

In UML, nothing prevents you from doing an aggregation between an abstract class and a concrete class. 
You should do that aggregation if conceptually, all concrete sub-classes of `Office` are also the targets of the aggregation of `Enterprise` class.
You should do that because it factorizes these relations and it brings  information that you don't need to repeat for each concrete `Office` subclass.

However, if conceptually, it exists at least one concrete subclass of `Office` which may not be the target of the aggregation from `Enterprise`, don't use the aggregation with as target the abstract class because otherwise your model would be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks, i understand  @davidxxx all concrete sub-class of Office are also the targets of the aggregation of Enterprise.

Comment: What would that mean if a concrete class aggregates abstract classes? I think it would mean absolutely nothing. I aggregate abstract money on my account. What can I buy from that money?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian I disagree with you because in the real workflow and at runtime in the process or in the application, the money concept which is abstract here will be a concrete thing.  And to do a parallel with OOP language, a concrete class may have a list of abstract instances and I am sure it would not mean absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Section **9.2 Classifiers** of the UML 2.5 spec states

> The isAbstract property of Classifier, when true, specifies that the Classifier is abstract, i.e., has no direct instances: every instance of the abstract Classifier shall be an instance of one of its specializations.

So basically, if you have a concrete class aggregating abstract classes, you can instantiate the class itself, but none of its aggregated classes. That seems pretty much pointless.

Vice versa, if an abstract class aggregates concrete classes you still have an abstract class. That would be fine.